# Error loading image to picturebox from mysql database. NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, mysql, picturebox

I am trying to get an image from database and display into a picture box. My code is below

```
private void getImage()
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionManager.connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            string query = "SELECT 'Image' FROM student_img WHERE ID =  @ID";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

            int id = 10;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

            var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Image");
            int count = ds.Tables["Images"].Rows.Count;

            if (count > 0)
            {
                var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Images"].Rows[count - 1]["Image"]);
                var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                picLogo.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Error!\n" + ex.Message, "Error Message",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

}
```

But I am getting NullReferenceException error. I also have another method maybe I can use this somehow but I am not sure how I can get data from the database as I am new to C#

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: `But I am getting NullReferenceException error`. On which line?

Comment: Why are you storing an image in a database? Databases shouldn't store files. You should store a link or reference to the image in the database, then go pull the image from a file server or web address based on that link.

Comment: you fill a table named "Image" then reference "Images". you dont need a dataadpter and dataset and datatable to read one field from a DB.  several things there need to be disposed

Comment: @Plutonix could you please explain more what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: @Necoras I get that I should not be storing files in DB but I am learning C# and want to learn how it works

Comment: Putting the Image field name between single quotes makes it a string not the name of the field. I could only suppose that the code that tries to retrieve bytes from the "Image" string will not be very right. If Image were a reserved keyword you should use backticks (ALT+096) but it is not so no need of anything around Image

Comment: @AAZ Practice is great, but only if you practice correctly. If you know you shouldn't store images in a database, why are you teaching yourself how to code up a solution incorrectly?

Comment: @Necoras What would you say would be the correct approach? I am working on a student database project so I am storing their images in the DB. It's just a personal project for me to learn c#. Its easier to upload an image into the database so I went with it.

Comment: Since it's a student project, presumably you either have a local database instance, or you have a central database that all of your students are using for their tests. If it's the former, I'd place a folder with images in it alongside the local database instance. If it's the latter, I'd place a folder with images in it on the database server. Then store the path to the images in the db. That way you're teaching your students database best practices, and how to handle file retrieval from disk as part of their lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix the problem, had to change

> Images

to

> Image

```
private void getImage()
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionManager.connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    string query = "SELECT Image FROM student_img WHERE ID =  @ID";

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

                    int id = 10;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

                    var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    var ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds, "Image");
                    int count = ds.Tables["Image"].Rows.Count;

                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        var data = (Byte[])(ds.Tables["Image"].Rows[count - 1]["Image"]);
                        var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
                        picLogo.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Error!\n" + ex.Message, "Error Message",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

        }
```